# Stop entr from running twice when file is saved from vim

Tags: vim, entr

I am trying to automate running any Python file in a directory when the file is saved. That way, the doctests will run, and I don't have to switch away from the editor.

My problem is that whenever I save a .py file, it runs twice.

Here's my command:

```
ls *.py | entr -p python /_
```

The -p is to postpone until the file is saved, and that works fine.

Comment: What editor do you use?

Comment: @user1686 I use vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue stems from how [vim writes files in two stages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27782763/2809427) by default. When inotify (which entr is based on) sees these events they're interpreted as two saves.

On my machine, this fixes the issue:

```
:set backupcopy=yes
```

You can add that to your `.vimrc` to make it permanent.